# Algorithm - Grouping List in unique pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics, minmax, code-complexity

I'm having difficulties with an assignment I've received, and I am pretty sure the problem's text is flawed. I've translated it to this:

---

Consider a list x[1..2n] with elements from {1,2,..,m}, m < n. Propose and implement in Python an algorithm with a complexity of O(n) that groups the elements into pairs (pairs of (x[i],x[j]) with i < j) such as every element is present in a single pair. For each set of pairs, calculate the maximum sum of the pairs, then compare it with the rest of the sets. Return the set that has the minimum of those.

```
For example, x = [1,5,9,3] can be paired in three ways:
(1,5),(9,3) => Sums: 6, 12 => Maximum 12
(1,9),(5,3) => Sums: 10, 8 => Maximum 10
(1,3),(5,9) => Sums: 4, 14 => Maximum 14
                              ----------
                              Minimum 10
Solution to be returned: (1,9),(5,3)
```

---

The things that strike me oddly are as follows:

- **Table contents definition** It says that there are elements of `1..2n, from {1..m}, m < n`. But if `m < n`, then there aren't enough elements to populate the list without duplicating some, which is not allowed. So then I would assume `m >= 2n`. Also, the example has `n = 2` but uses elements that are greater than 1, so I assume that's what they meant.
- **O(n) complexity?** So is there a way to combine them in a single loop? I can't think of anything.

---

**My Calculations:**

```
For n = 4:
Number of ways to combine: 6
Valid ways: 3

For n = 6
Number of ways to combine: 910
Valid ways: 15

For n = 8
Number of ways to combine: >30 000
Valid ways: ?
```

So obviously, I cannot use brute force and then figure out if it is valid after then. The formula I used to calculate the total possible ways is

```
C(C(n,2),n/2)
```

---

**Question:**

Is this problem wrongly written and impossible to solve? If so, what conditions should be added or removed to make it feasible? If you are going to suggest some code in python, remember *I cannot use any prebuilt functions of any kind*. Thank you

Comment: `append()` is a prebuilt function. You can't use it as well? Also why does this matter? If anyone would be so nice to solve your assignment, will not you be able to rewrite it without 'prebuilt functions'?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Well, those are allowed. I mean functions that do complex calculations that replace what I need to do. For example, I cannot use something that generates the combinations for me.

Comment: It doesn't say there are no duplicates, only that each element of the list appears in one pair.

Comment: @PeterWood how would you have duplicates if every element is present in a single pair?

Comment: `m < n` and the list has `2n` elements, so there must be duplicates, as you said.

Comment: When you are given the list, is it sorted? I see that it isn't sorted in your example - is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, that's exactly my point. It implies there are and that there aren't which is a paradox. Suppose my assumtion that `m >= 2n` is true and continue from there.

Comment: No there is no paradox. You are allowed duplicates.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget There is no specification if the list is sorted or not. If it makes the problem significantly easier, I'll cheat and allow the presumption of a sorted input.

Comment: I thought about it some more. I think that this problem boils down to a more complex version of [the stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem), whose solution requires quadratic time. If that analysis is correct, then it's impossible to solve this question in linear time if the input list is not sorted. But if you can assume m<<n (not m<n), then you should be able to solve the unsorted case in linear time as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a sorted list:

```
def answer(L):
    return list(zip(L[:len(L)//2], L[len(L)//2:][::-1]))
```

Or if you want to do it more manually:

```
def answer(L):
    answer = []
    for i in range(len(L)//2):
        answer.append((L[i], L[len(L)-i-1)]))
    return answer
```

Output:

```
In [3]: answer([1,3,5,9])
Out[3]: [(1, 9), (3, 5)]
```

Comment: Could you describe the manual version of the algorithm naturally so I can understand the thought process?

Comment: @Jadarma: you want the minimum max-sum of all combinations in your result. This happens when you combine the two mid-valued elements, the smallest and the largest element, and so forth. As a result, if your list is sorted, then simply start combining the elements from either end, until you reach the middle. Then return that list of combinations

Comment: Thanks, indeed it works! But this is considering the list as sorted, what happens if it isn't There is no sorting algorithm in O(n). How would it be solved in that case?

Comment: @Jadarma: I'm thinking about it, but it's going to be tough

Comment: I think this was the intended solution, though.As there are aspects of the problem that are still flawed, such as the n < m rule that the example itself is breaking.